# Hide and show divs with text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are a lot of these threads but none seem to really fit me.

I have 5 dives with text like "this is div1, to div5". These are **always** gonna be shown.
And i have 5 hidden divs with text belonging to each div, that are gonna show if i click on my shown divs.

If I click div1, i want to show the hidden div1.

Right now I'm using a click function(jQuery) for every div which works but doesn't look very good in code. There has to be a better way. Any advise?

I do **NOT** want any of the divs to be hyperlinks, which seem to be the solution on a lot of similar threads on here.

EDIT: This is my current code.(can't get jsfiddle to work)

**html**

```
<div class="showing_div">
<p>This is a showing div</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden_div" style="display: none;>
<p>This div is hidden</p>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('showing_div').click(function() {

$('hidden_div').toggle();   

})
```

Comment: share the jQuery code you have, otherwise we don't know what you have done

Comment: share the HTML code you have, otherwise we don't know what you have done

Comment: Make a fiddle of your code in jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com .Other wise , it will be next to impossible at knowing what you have done and what you want ?

Comment: it's more like an accordation or tabs?

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/pmendonca/pjgR6/

Comment: @PauloMendonça You can simply use: `$('div.collapse div').hide();`.

Comment: Sorry guys, I have edited my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This are the most used techniques:

### target element using `.index()` and `.eq()`

```
<div id="clickables">
    <div>CLICK 1</div>
    <div>CLICK 2</div>
</div>

<div id="togglables">
    <div>text 1</div>
    <div>text 2</div>
</div>
```

```
$(function(){

    $("#clickables div").click(function(){
         var idx = $(this).index();
         $('#togglables div').eq( idx ).slideToggle();
    });

});
```

<sub>**Pros:** you can keep a really clean HTML markup, no need to assign additional classes or ID

**Cons:** don't put other elements inside the parents otherwise you might mess the index count</sub>

---

### target element using `.next()` <sub>or other jQuery traversal methods</sub>

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="clickable">CLICK 1</div>
    <div>text 1</div>
    <div class="clickable">CLICK 2</div>
    <div>text 2</div>
</div>
```

```
$(function(){

    $("#menu .clickable").click(function(){
         $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
    });

});
```

---

### target specific element using `ID`

```
    <div class="clickable" id="_1" > CLICK 1 </div>
    <div class="clickable" id="_2" > CLICK 2 </div>

    <div id="togglable_1"> text 1 </div>
    <div id="togglable_2"> text 2 </div>
```

```
$(function(){

    $(".clickable").click(function(){
         $("#togglable"+ this.id).slideToggle();
    });

});
```

<sub>**Pros:** You can target elements unlogically positioned in the DOM

**Cons:** Verbose HTML; Unflexible and hardly maintainable code.</sub>

Comment: +1 You covered two out of three situations (last one is nothing is ordered in the DOM). Might by suitable for almost all situations. :)

Comment: @insertusernamehere I was writing the last one :D

Comment: Roko C. Buljan - Wow! What a post, thank you a LOT! This will save my life :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('#'+text).show();
});
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DGbT3/1161/)**

Comment: once you change the text (CMS or other) you're pretty much screwed

Comment: yeah you r right ..but as he has mentioned text..i supposed this might work atleast in this case....

Answer (score 0):

As @Roko C. Buljan nicely showed there are many ways of doing it.

This is how I usually do using **[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)** jQuery function:

```
<div class="clickable" data-hidden="d1">CLICK 1</div>
<div id="d1" class="hidden">text 1</div>
<div class="clickable" data-hidden="d2">CLICK 2</div>
<div id="d2" class="hidden">text 2</div>
```

```
$(".clickable").click(function() {
    $("#" + $(this).data("hidden")).toggle();  
});
```

This way it does not matter how I organize my DOM elements. I only need to care to identify the right `id` in every data-hidden attribute.

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3u98y/)**

Comment: Thanks for the response! I didn't even have time to edit my post before I got all the answers I needed, great help as always :)