# jquery toggle content by header

Tags: jquery, toggle

for the following HTML:

```
 <h1 id="t1">First Title</h1>
 <p class="contents" id="c1">First Content</p>

 <h1 id="t2">Second Title</h1>
 <p class="contents" id="c2">Second Content</p>

 <h1 id="t3">Third Title</h1>
 <p class="contents" id="c3">Third Content</p>

<!-- etc... -->
```

I'd like to use jquery to `slideToggle` the content for each specific header. Ie: clicking on id="t2", I'd like "c2" to toggle.

Thanks for your suggestions or code!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide and show divs with text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386400/hide-and-show-divs-with-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('h1').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/V4xFG/)**

Answer (score 0):

use class for your h1 instead, since it fits much better in your requirement..

then try this:

`$('h1.h1class').click(function() {
$(this).next('p.contents').slideToggle(500);
});`